# Open image using terminal in linux

Tags: bash, image, terminal

I am trying to open an image with the terminal and set the image viewer to fullscreen and diaporama mode.

I am currently using `xdg-open` which allow me to open the image but the window is not in fullscreen mode. I tried force the fullscreen mode using F11 and F5 for diaporama mode but I am working on a computer that doesn't allow the installation of external tools.

Is there a way to force the fullscreen and diaporama mode without external tools ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your default image viewer application ?

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean external tools ? If you can select a different image viewer, which you can setup to start full screen, then `xdg-open` will use it.
Alternatively you can try something like `feh` instead of `xdg-open`, `feh` reads the fehrc file where you can define the starting options.

Comment: `xdg-open` calls a default image viewer, isn't ? so my suggestion was to either call a default image viewer which supports full screen the way you need it, or use a terminal image viewer such as `feh` which support full screen out of box. `Feh` also can be a default image viewer, but no idea is it supports diaporama mode

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `gnome-open` to open your file. It also has full screen mode(F11) and slideshow mode.

'eog'(Eye of GNOME) is also a good option.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you can use the image viewer that comes by default with it, using the command:

```
$ eog my_pic.jpg
```

And that's it, if you do not have that image viewer then you can just download whatever you like and open it from the terminal in the same way. To exit you can close the opened window or by typing ctrl + c in your terminal to close the process.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way!

**$gio open simpleImageFile.png**